# Choosing Which Controller Should Contain an Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I'm having a problem deciding when to create a new controller and which controller should contain certain action methods.

I'm currently building an auction website in which users post items and other users bid to win the auction. There's a whole panel dedicated to the user (user account/profile). In this panel, the user can view/edit his personal information, view his listings, his bids and the status of the auctions in which he participates, view/add his address(es) for item delivery/shipping purposes, and his personal messages (inbox).

So, naturally I would think there has to be an `ItemController`, `UserController`, `BiddingController` (not sure), `AddressController`, and `MessageController` and probably some other controllers. But how do I decide that I actually need a controller, and how do I decide in which controller does a certain action method belong? Currently, I have alot of stuff inside the `UserController` (because those are the bids, items/listings, addresses, messages... etc of the User) but I'm not quite sure about it.

How do I decide what controllers to create and when to create them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I stick to [RESTful conventions](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SimplyRestfulRouting&referringTitle=Documentation&ProjectName=mvccontrib). So once you have identified the resources it is easy.

Comment: I like that. So if I got that straight, all of those mentioned above should be taken out to their respective controllers.

Answer (score 1):

I try to organize my controllers by concept. Basically I want the action on the controller most related to it. For example, I would consider viewing your own listings to be more related to searching auctions or viewing a single auction than to editing your own profile because the page's model would be emphasizing the auctions, not the user's name, reputation, etc.

In your case I'd probably consider something like this:

```
AuctionController
    - Search
    - View
    - PlaceBid
    - Create
    - MyListings

ShippingController
    - Payment
    - Location
    - Confirm

AccountController
    - Profile
    - EditProfile
    - OrderStatus
    - Inbox

FeedbackController
    - View (for a specific user)
    - Leave (for giving feedback)

AuthenticationController
    - Login
```